# Keyboard layout English US international not working properly on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: keyboard-layout, compose-key

I usually use two keyboard layout, plain `English (US)`, and `Englis (US, intl. with dead keys)` in order to type `'` and press `e`, to make this: `é`.

It worked in many distributions for many years, now on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04.5 I have problems. The layout lntl. with dead keys work as the plain US layout: I can not type `é`.

Even the `Englis (US, intl. with AltGr dead keys)` does not work properly. I obtain `é` by pressing `AltGr`+`e`, but if press `AltGr`+`'` followed by `e` I obtain `'e`.

I do not wont to use the compose key, neither AltGr, I would like to obtain the standard behavior of `English (US, intl. with dead keys)`.

Comment: if you press AltGr+' together then e you get ê

Comment: Thinking of [bug #1890875](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1890875). Did you relogin or reboot after having added `English (US, intl. with dead keys)`?

Comment: thanks @GunnarHjalmarsson, the layout switch correctly. I found that `English (UK, intl. with dead keys)` work ad expected, so most probably there is a bug in `English (US, intl. with dead keys)`.

Comment: The latter layout works for me on 18.04, so I don't think it's a problem with the layout itself. [Bug #1573755](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1573755) comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @GunnarHjalmarsson for pointing me to Bug#1573755.
Removing ~/.xinputrc has solved the problem for me.